# Symfony relationship guide to sync two fields from different entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, sonata-admin

I have started to use symfony sonata admin project.I am stuck at following case.
I have and entity called carrier,purchase and supplier

Supplier can be assigned a carrier from dropdown and its foreign key is stored in supplier table.
Now in purchase,i want to change the carrier for any supplier , but it is not getting updated in supplier table

```
class Purchase
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier")
     */
    private $supplier;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Carrier")
     */
    private $supplierCarrier;

class Supplier
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier")
     */
    private $supplier;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Carrier")
     */
    private $supplierCarrier;

class Carrier
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": false}, nullable=false)
     */
    private $required = false;
```

Basically what i want is the carrier for supplier should be synced in supplier table when it is updated from purchase entity.
Is there any way to achieve above.?
Any feedback would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try manually add the second entity arguments? When you set values to first entity you must call method from second entity. I don't know the ready solution from Symfony for your problem.